# Swift: User default values not being saved/ loaded when app is opened and closed

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a global settings variable (SettingsVariable.settingOne) that is changed by the user during the apps runtime. I want to make the users change permanent, but at the moment every time the app is then reloaded it reverts to the original values e.g. user changes value to false, but then when the app is rerun the variables value changes back to the original value.

When the value is changed the following code is called (swift 2):

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "settingOne")
```

and when the app is closed:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(SettingsVariables.settingOne, forKey: "settingOne")
}
```

then once the app is opened again:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("settingOne")

        return true
}
```

But the value of settingOne keeps reverting back to the default value of 'true' set originally within the application.

SettingsVariables.settingOne is contained within a struct:

```
import UIKit

struct SettingsVariables {

    static var settingOne = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `synchronize` to save `NSUserDefaults`.

So your code must be

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(SettingsVariables.settingOne, forKey: "settingOne")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added that to the code but it still isnt loading the changed value.

Comment: 1) You normally don't need to call `synchronize`. 2) `applicationWillTerminate` isn't always called.

Comment: I have the code in the applicationDidEnterBackground method as well but does not work

Comment: This answer is wrong. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40809748/2227743

Answer (score 2):

Now Apple documentation suggests to use `CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication)` instead of calling `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` which is marked as a deprecated method.

Comment: CFPreferencesAppSynchronize has been available since iOS 2.0, this is not news. And you don't need to call this either anyway. Please all have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40809748/2227743) which has excellent explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize the values          `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added that to the code but it still isnt loading the changed value.

Comment: applicationWillTerminate method will only call when we kill the app from multiTasking. Try to add the save logic in "applicationDidEnterBackground" method.

Comment: I have the coe in both the applicationWillTerminate and applicationDidEnterBackground methods but not working

Comment: in applicationWillTerminate method you are using "SettingsVariables.settingOne" value for saving in NSUserDefaults, if this method calls at last, then the NSUSerDefaults value will get overwrited.

Comment: If you have value in NSUserDefaults then you have to update the SettingsVariables.settingOne value based on NSUserDefault value. I hope this could help you.

Answer (score -1):

this what I use for getting element from NSUserDefaults , `UserDataKey` is just Enum

```
func userDataForKey(key: UserDataKey) -> String? {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let value: AnyObject = userDefaults.objectForKey(key.rawValue) {
        return value as? String
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

and this for saving

```
 func setUserData(value: AnyObject?, key: UserDataKey) -> () {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(value, forKey: key.rawValue)
}
```