# My App logs me out from all apps on signout

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm developing an iOS app with Swift.

on my iPhone, when I logout of my app, it logs me out of facebook, Line and other apps.

the is my code:

```
Overlay.shared.show()
Auth.logout { (success) in
    UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.setUserToken(value: "")
    let loginController = LoginController()
    loginController.animateLogo = false
    Overlay.shared.remove()
    self.present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and for `UserDefaults`:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    enum UserDefaultsKeys: String {
        case isLoggedIn
        case userToken
    }

    func setIsLoggedIn(value: Bool) {
        set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isLoggedIn.rawValue)
        synchronize()
    }

    func setUserToken(value: String) {
        set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.userToken.rawValue)
        synchronize()
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It definitely doesn't do that

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: That code doesn't log you out of Facebook or do anything outside of your app.  It isn't possible.

Comment: well each time I click sign out of my app, facebook and line ask me to log in again

Comment: I have implemented login with touchid but I don't use it, so I don't think that is the touchid

Comment: FYI - unrelated but remove the needless calls to `synchronize`.

Comment: as I know, I need synchronize to save the edited values, right?

Comment: @Yaser No, you do not. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40809748/1226963

Comment: I suppose, removing synchronize will resolve my problem

Comment: I think my problem was solved, after removing synchronize, I tried to login and logout many times and everything is fine