# Best way to initialize non-optional var if optional is nil in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I would like to initialize a variable `obj` by taking it from `UserDefaults`, which returns a `String?`, and if it's `nil` build the value and assign it.

The following code works, but, at the end, my `obj` is a `String?` while I want it to be a `String` (since it can't be `nil` at this stage).

```
var obj = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "my_key")// Here, obj is a String?
if obj == nil {
    obj =  ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString// Returns, a String
    defaults.set(obj, forKey: "my_key")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
// Here, obj is still a String?
```

Is there a good pattern / best practice for this kind of situation ?

Comment: FYI - there is [no need to call `synchronize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808072/when-and-why-should-you-use-nsuserdefaultss-synchronize-method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the nil-coalescing operator `??` with an
"immediately evaluated closure":

```
let obj = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "my_key") ?? {
    let obj = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    UserDefaults.standard.set(obj, forKey: "my_key")
    return obj
}()

print(obj) // Type is `String`
```

If the user default is not set, the closure is executed. 
The closure creates and sets the user default (using a *local* `obj`
variable) and returns it to the caller, so that
it is assigned to the outer `obj` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Optional Binding. You can read up on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

```
let obj: String

if let string = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "my_key") {
    obj = string
} else {
    obj = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    UserDefaults.standard.set(obj, forKey: "my_key")
}

print(obj)
```

Comment: You can even `let obj: String`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an implicitly unwrapped optional, like this:

```
var obj: String! = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "my_key")// Here, obj is a (possibly `nil`) `String!`
if obj == nil {
    obj =  ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString // Returns, a String
    defaults.set(obj, forKey: "my_key")
    defaults.synchronize()
}

// Here, obj is a non-`nil` `String!`, which will work the same as a `String`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `guard let` or `if let`.

1) **`guard let`**  (not common for your case, though)

```
guard let obj = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "my_key") else { 
    // guard failed - obj is nil; perform something and return
    obj =  ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    defaults.set(obj, forKey: "my_key")
    return 
}

// obj is not nil, you have it at your disposal
print(obj)
```

2) **`if let`**

```
if let obj = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "my_key") {
   // obj exists
} else {
    let obj =  ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    defaults.set(obj, forKey: "my_key")
    print(obj)
}
```

(!) Also, there really is no more need to call `defaults.synchronize()`:

> Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database
>   and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.
>
> <sub>https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize</sub>

Comment: That `if let` example won't work as you're trying to assign a value to `obj` which is a let constant. Also, it tries to overwrite the value returned from `UserDefaults` which is the opposite of what is requested

Comment: You are right. Wasn't attentive enough. Will correct.