# UserDefaults not working on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, nsuserdefaults, xctest

`UserDefaults` does not appear to function in an XCTest when running on Linux. I'm running the below test but `userDefaults.string(forKey: "key")` returns `nil` on Linux when on macOS it returns the correct value and passes.

I'm using Docker to execute the tests on Linux. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM swiftdocker/swift

WORKDIR /package

COPY . ./

RUN swift package resolve
RUN swift package clean
RUN swift test --parallel
```

The test file:

```
import XCTest

class UserDefaultsTests: XCTestCase {

    func testUserDefaults() {

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        userDefaults.set("value", forKey: "key")

        _ = userDefaults.synchronize()

        XCTAssertEqual(userDefaults.string(forKey: "key"), "value") //nil is not equal to "value"
    }

    static var allTests = [
        ("testUserDefaults", testUserDefaults)
    ]
}
```

`UserDefaults` appears to be [implemented in Swift Core Libs here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/UserDefaults.swift), which is available on Linux, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but the call to `synchronize` is unnecessary.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the feedback. I just thought I'd add it to be sure. In my mind, if it's not necessary it should be deprecated, but it isn't.

Comment: I don't mean it's not needed ever, I mean it's not needed in your code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808072/when-and-why-should-you-use-nsuserdefaultss-synchronize-method

Comment: @rmaddy With or without `synchronize` it doesn't work on the above Docker image. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe try `userDefaults.string(forKey: "key") as Any, ...`

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks but the result is still nil.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Swift 4.0.2 and Swift 4.1 (snapshot): it's working only with Swift 4.1.