# Issue in updating value from `UserDefaults` in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I'm sending a string value from my vc2 to vc1 through `UserDefaults`. But when I move back to vc1 from vc2 through back button the value doesn't update. I'm getting value in vc1 in `viewWillAppear` method. But my value does not update. I navigate from vc1 to vc2 through push method.

This is how i stored the value in user default in vc2,

```
  cartItems = cartItems + 1
  print(cartItems)
  let badgeCount = String(cartItems)
  print(badgeCount)
  let rightBarButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
  let badge = String(badgeCount)
  rightBarButton?.addBadge(text: badge)
  UserDefaults.standard.set(badgeCount, forKey: "cartsItems")
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

and in vc1 i get like this in viewWillAppear delegate,

```
 let count =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "cartsItems")
 print(count)
```

When i come back to vc1 from vc2 through back button value never update and when i call some other vc and than call again vc1 it gets update. How can i update value at that time?

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: What type is `badgeCount`? Is is possible you are setting an Integer but trying to retrieve a String?

Comment: i have edited please check. @Anbu.karthik

Comment: `UserDefaults` is inappropriate to share data between controllers. Use callbacks, protocol / delegate or notifications.

Comment: So many `vc2` and `vc1` are confusing me. Could you please just tell where you're setting the value and where is not getting?

Comment: badgeCount is a string that i want to send. @DejanSkledar

Comment: i'm setting value in vc2 and want to get in vc1 in viewWillAppearDelegate. @TheTiger

Comment: In which method of `vc2` you are setting the value?

Comment: i'm having a button when i click it there is set the value. @TheTiger

Comment: try this `UserDefaults.standard.set(badge, forKey: "cartsItems")
`

Comment: @Awais Can you please add a log just before calling set method in VC2?

Comment: `viewWillAppearDelegate` is not a thing. The method is `viewWillAppear(_:)`. Post your entire `viewWillAppear(_:)` method, as well as the entire method from VC1 that sets the value in UserDefaults. Also show us the console output from your print statements.

Comment: for such senario delegate is best option

Comment: It is getting the value i have printed it but issue is coming when i come from some other vc to vc1 it makes value nil. It should maintain the same value. @Anbu.karthik

Comment: Ignoring your misuse of UserDefaults, [there is no reason to call synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808072/when-and-why-should-you-use-nsuserdefaultss-synchronize-method).

Comment: why not to call synchronize? @rmaddy

Comment: @Awais Please click the link I provided.

Comment: if i don't synchronize it will it update the value even app is kill? @rmaddy

Comment: @Awais Again, please click the link I provided and read the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the proper way to do this is with a simple **delegate protocol** to transfer data from one `VC2` to another `VC1`.

Below are the steps how to work with the `protocol`.

**In `VC2`** ` do the following steps.

Just above your class declaration declare your delegate.

```
protocol MyDelegate:class {
    func sendDataBack(value: Int)
}
```

In `class` declare a `weak variable` of your `delegate`

```
weak var myDelegateObj: MyDelegate?
```

and when you `dismiss the VC` just call the delegate with line

```
myDelegateObj?.sendDataBack(value: yourIntegrerValue)
```

---

Now go to your `VC1` and go to the line where you have pushed `VC1` to `VC2` 
 and do the following.

```
vc2.myDelegateObj = self // vc2 is VC2 objcet
```

and implement the method your delegate in the `VC1`

```
func sendDataBack(value: Int) {
     print(value)   
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: let me try. @Roshan Singh Bisht

Comment: let me know if any confusions!

Comment: where should i declare this in vc1? vc2.myDelegateObj = self . @Roshan Singh Bisht

Comment: declare it where you have taken the vc2 object in vc1 or where you trying to push from vc1 to vc2

Comment: i have declared there but it crashes on that point where i declare that on my push view controller. @Roshan Singh Bisht

Comment: This is what i write in my vc1 
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantMenuDetailVC") as! RestaurantMenuDetailVC
                        vc.categoryModel = categoryModel
                        vc.subCategoryModel = subCategoryModel
                        vc.AddonCategoryModel = AddonCategoryModel
                        vc.myDelegateObj = self as! MyDelegate
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) . @Roshan Singh Bisht

Comment: you don't need to do this  `vc.myDelegateObj = self as! MyDelegate ` instead do this  the `class ViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate ` and just declare  `vc.myDelegateObj = self`

Means you need to make your `ViewController` conform to `MyDelegate`  by doing this  `class ViewController: UIViewController,MyDelegate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171196/discussion-between-roshan-singh-bisht-and-awais).

Comment: i got the value thanks a lot :) . @Roshan Singh Bisht

Comment: do upvote the answer if you find it useful in anyway, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something similar to what you are doing. I am translating the app to other languages (localization). So when I choose one language on a VC2, I go back to VC1 and the strings in VC1 should update according to the language choosen.

The language is stored in Userdefaults().

I think I know why you are having this problem. To realize what is happening try to write this in VC1:

```
let count =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "cartsItems") // I suppose this is a global variable.
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print("This is the value of the global variable: \(count)")
    print("This is the value of Userdefaults directly: \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "cartsItems"))")     

}
```

You would expect both results to be the same. However, the first one, from the global variable, will be not updated; whereas the second one, using Userdefaults directly, is updated.

I suppose this is because when you load VC1, the view is loaded and the variables get their values. When you open VC2, it opens above VC1. When you go back to VC1 you are not loading it again, but going back to what is already loaded. And the global variable remains with the same value as in the beginning.

Hope that helps.