# How to check if an NSArray in NSUserDefaults contains a specific NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, nspredicate

How do I check for a string that I added to a `NSMutableArray` in `userDefaults`. I have tried to use:

```
[arrayOfSavedStrings containsObject:currentString];
```

But that returns false.

How would I use a predicate or for loop to get this value?

I am trying to save values to an array in user defaults every time `checkForSavedString` is called.

```
- (void)checkForSavedString {

    NSString *stringImAdding = self.stringProperty;

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arrayOfStrings addObject:stringImAdding];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:arrayOfStrings forKey:@"SavedStrings"];

}
```

I am trying to check if the value I saved to `userDefaults` in the `checkForSavedString` method is present in the array.

```
self.stringProperty = self.stringFromSomewhereElse;

NSString *currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.stringProperty];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSArray *arrayOfSavedStrings = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"SavedStrings"];


if ([arrayOfSavedStrings containsObject:currentString]) {

    // my code
}
```

Comment: At least use `arrayForKey` rather than `objectForKey`.

Comment: Do you want to add or replace `appFormId` in `registrationFormSubmission`? Why do you do `stringWithFormat`?

Comment: @vadian +1 arrayForKey

Comment: There is [no reason to call synchronize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808072/when-and-why-should-you-use-nsuserdefaultss-synchronize-method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the solution was to use a predicate to look for `currentString` in `arrayOfSavedStrings` and filter that array to only include what I was searching for.

```
- (void)checkForSavedString {

    NSString *stringImAdding = self.stringProperty;

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfSavedStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"SavedStrings"]];
    [arrayOfSavedStrings addObject:stringImAdding];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:arrayOfSavedStrings forKey:@"SavedStrings"];

}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` checking for the saved string

```
self.stringProperty = self.stringFromSomewhereElse;

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfSavedStrings = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"SavedStrings"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", self.stringProperty];
NSArray *results = [arrayOfSavedStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if (results.count >= 1) {
    // my code
}
```

Comment: You write a string and search a number? Do you replace `RegistrationAppFormId` each time with one `appFormId` in `registrationFormSubmission`?